# Why sd function is invalid in rapply()?

Tags: r

I tried to generate all sd of a list of list but it shows this error:

```r
Error in rapply(d, sd, how = "list") : invalid 'f' argument
```

My code:

```r
d3 <-rapply(d, sd, how = 'list')
```

`d` is a list and is there any way to generate all sd of list?

```
d <-list()
for (i in 1:19){

  d[[i]] <- rnorm(30,mean = 25,sd= 8)
}
```

BTW,

```r
d2 <-rapply(d, mean, how='list')
```

this can be run.

Comment: We don't have `d`, or anything that would let us guess what it looks like.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I can't replicate this error. The code runs for me. Did you create a variable named `sd` that shadows the base `sd` function? What if you try `rapply(d, stats::sd, how = 'list')`

Comment: @onyambu If you just run `sd <- 5` before this, you'll get the same error. It doesn't have to be a function. `rapply` doesn't call `match.fun()` to specifically find functions.

Comment: @MrFlick you right. Seems rapply does not follow the rules of R. Thanks

Comment: On 2023-07-26 it worked for me.